# Gitlab CI doesn't pull updated docker image from cr to EC2 - [image] is up-to-date

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have followed [this guide](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-ec2-with-docker-and-gitlab)

to create a CI/CD pipeline with Gitlab, Docker and AWS EC2. I managed it to work with some modifications, but now the problem I have is the following:

1. The first time I push my code the pipeline works ok, images are stored on Gitlab's container registry, they are pulled and deployed on my EC2.
2. If I push a new commit to my repo, when pulling images from container registry with `deploy.sh` script I have this response: `[MY_IMAGE] is up-to-date`, when in reality it is not. In fact if I run the command manually from the aws machine it detects the new images and pulls them.

I tried tagging images with `$CI_COMMIT_SHA`, but no luck.

Any way I can make this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I didn't set the right env variables to use in the `setup_env.sh`. Now everything is ok.

Comment: Can you explain? I have a similar setup but the latest changes from gitlab isn't updated on ec2.